# UDP DatagramPacket извлечь данные в строку

Tags: java, android

```
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String modifiedSentence = new String(packet.getData());
                System.out.println("SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
```

В консоль выводятся куча байт, как из modifiedSentence получить строку?

Comment: System.out.println(); в Android Studio , а разница есть? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
String str = new String(buf, "UTF-8");
```

или так:

```
String str = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

вывод:

```
System.out.println("SERVER: " + str);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло: String str = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());   Самое интересное что ваш первый пример, и тот который в оригинальном коде данные получает нормальные, но после данных идут непонятные данные. Второй пример мне очень помог, вы сильный специалист. Не могу поставить балл т.к нет еще репутации ))

Comment: @SergeyKuntsevich [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)